# How to access elements that were created in script?

Tags: javascript

In the function below, I create cards that have a toggle button and remove button. However, when I try to access the buttons with a queryselector, I get null. Anyone know how to access elements that were created in a different file? I can provide the full files if needed.

```
function updateDisplay() {
    for (i = 0; i < myLibrary.length; i++){
    let div = document.createElement('div');
    let title = document.createElement('h5');
    let author = document.createElement('h5');
    let pages = document.createElement('h5');
    let isRead = document.createElement('h5');
    let removeButton = document.createElement('button');
    let toggleButton = document.createElement('button');
    div.classList.add('card');
    title.classList.add('title');
    author.classList.add('author');
    pages.classList.add('pages');
    isRead.classList.add('isRead');
    removeButton.classList.add('removeButton');
    toggleButton.classList.add('toggleButton');
    title.textContent = myLibrary[i].title;
    author.textContent = myLibrary[i].author;
    pages.textContent = `${myLibrary[i].pages} pages`;
    isRead.textContent = myLibrary[i].isRead ? 'Read' : 'Unread';
    removeButton.textContent = 'Remove';
    toggleButton.textContent = 'Toggle Read Status';
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. take a [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Sounds like you try to reference them before they are created..... Hard to guess with what was provided.

Comment: Also your code is not complete.....

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is obvious you're creating the elements but not appending the into the body.
you'll have to append each element you create like the following example:

```
var element= document.createElement("div");            // Create a <div> element
element.innerHTML = "some content";                   // Insert text
document.body.appendChild(element);                  // Append <div> to <body>
```

> note that you can do `document.body.append(div,title,author,pages,isRead,removeButton,toggleButton);`
> to append them all in one line